# Strange behavior in MKL cblas_idamax

Tags: c, intel-mkl

I am trying to use the **cblas_idamax** function from the **Intel MKL library** to get the maximum value for each column of a input matrix. In some executions I get the right answer, but in others I get wrong indexes. This is an example of my C code:

```
const MKL_INT nByRow = 2;
const MKL_INT matrix_size = nByRow*nByRow
double * colMaxs = (double *)mkl_malloc(sizeof(double)*nByRow, 64);
double * matrix = (double *)mkl_malloc(sizeof(double)*nByRow, 64);

// matrix is CblasRowMajor
// 1 2
// 3 4
matrix[0]=1;
matrix[1]=2;
matrix[2]=3;
matrix[3]=4;

for(size_t i=0;i<nByRow;i++){
    // calculate the index of the max value in each column
    maxPos = cblas_idamax(matrix_size, matrix + i , nByRow);

    // save the max value
    colMaxs[i] = (*matrix)[i + (maxPos * nByRow)];
}
```

some times **cblas_idamax** returns index 1 for each column, which is correct, but other times returns 3 for each column. I supuse this is a memory-related problem. If someone has some clue about what is happening here I would be very grateful :)

My computer is a MacBook Pro Retina early 2015

OS: Sierra

Processor: Intel 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`maxPos` is the absolute position in the "vector" not the row index. And it also seems that you have one indirection too much.

To obtain the element value you should do

```
// save the max value
colMaxs[i] = matrix[i + maxPos];
```

To obtain the row index, you'd need to compute `(maxPos-i)/nByRow` or so.

Comment: Thanks!. Finally I changed the matrix_size parameter (size of the array) to nByRow (size of the vector) and it worked as expected. :)